# python console command stalls script

Tags: python, console, libreoffice

My workflow usually follows this chain:

- open the sample data file in libreoffice using the soffice command, so the sample data file can be connected to, this is a console command:

  ```
   $ soffice --calc --accept="socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager" /path/to/sample/data.ods
  ```
- run python console and type following connection commands:

  ```
   >>> sys.path.append("/path/to/uno_lib/.local/lib/python3")    
   >>> import uno
   >>> local_context = uno.getComponentContext()
   >>> resolver = local_context.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", local_context)
   >>> ctx = resolver.resolve("uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext")
   >>> smgr = ctx.ServiceManager
   >>> desktop = smgr.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", ctx)
   >>> document = desktop.getCurrentComponent()
  ```
- use uno commands to extract data

  ```
   pseudo-code >>> document.getSheet("data").getCellRange("B5", "H15")
  ```

Obviously, I would like to put all this into a file "connect" and function "connection" like:

**connect.py**

```
import os
import uno
def connection():
    os.system(soffice --calc --accept="socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager" /path/to/sample/data.ods)
    context ...
    resolver
    ctx ...
    smgr ....
    desktop ...
    document ...
    return document
```

so I can simply go:

```
$ python
>>> import connect
>>> document = connection()
>>> document.getSheet("DataSheet").getCellRange("B5", "H15")
```

OOh how much I would love this :)

With question: when I call the function "connection()", the console stalls at the system command opening the calc file, only when I close the calc file, the script continues but then it does not connect any more, as the file is closed :( how can I circumvent this?

Comment: Am I right in guessing that you are on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way is to use a shell script instead of a system call to start LibreOffice.

```
./start_soffice_listening.sh
python
>>> import connect
>>> document = connection()
```

Here is the shell script I use:

```
if [ "$1" == "-headless" ]; then
    echo "Opening headless (use 'pkill loffice' and 'pkill soffice.bin' to end"
    loffice "--accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;" --writer --headless --nologo --nofirststartwizard --nolockcheck --norestore &
else
    loffice "--accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;" --writer &
fi
```

Otherwise you will need threads and sleep commands to interact with the operating system from within Python. This is more difficult and less reliable than starting LO directly.

Comment: so how would you put the shell script in the python file?  so I can import and connect.  It seems like you are still running a shell command outside of the python file ...

Comment: " It seems like you are still running a shell command outside of the python file" - Yes, that is the whole point of my answer. But if you are up for writing threaded code (hint: do the system call in a separate thread and try sleeping 10 seconds before continuing) and don't mind LibreOffice crashing or being slower then you can do everything from within the python interpreter instead.

Comment: cant you put the shell command inside a python script?  and also, I am just reading one row of values, no need for any other functionality, no need for threads and no matter if it crashes regularly, how would i do that from within the module?

Comment: It sounds like you're failing to see the problem. The python interpreter is a circle, and anything running inside the circle is not going to have the freedom it normally would. So run LO outside the circle by making the call first before starting python, or start it from a separate terminal window where python is not running. Does that make sense? As far as keeping things simple, yes I agree, which is why I recommend the simple solution of using a shell script instead of a more complex solution that requires threading.

Comment: I get that you don't want to give up, and maybe if you work on it you can come up with a solution that meets your needs better. However I stand by my answer as generally the preferred solution, and that is unlikely to change even if you keep asking me for a loophole. Someone else is welcome to answer differently of course.

Comment: giving up is not in my dictionary, unfortunately, thanks for your time, sorry for my persistence, I will keep you posted if I found a possible work-around